# How to repeat animation in svg from last stop point?

Tags: svg

I have animated a path, which starts on moseover and stop+reset animation on mouseout, fill="freeze" just stop it, but when I mouseover again it starts from the beginning

```html
<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; viewBox="0 0 500.1 489.1" class="svg-gears"> 
  <rect id="deepPink-rectangle" width="300" height="300" x="100" y="100" fill="deepPink" >
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="rotate"
      dur="6s"
      from="0 315 184"
      to="360 315 184"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      begin="mouseover"
      end="mouseout"
    />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

How can I continue from the last freeze position?

Comment: Add, please, the code of the entire svg file, otherwise it's hard for you to show how this is done

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this with SMIL animations, but easily with CSS animations, which have a [`animation-play-state="paused"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-play-state-property):

```css
#deepPink-rectangle {
  animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  transform-origin: 250px 250px;
}
#deepPink-rectangle:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500.1 489.1">
  <rect id="deepPink-rectangle" width="300" height="300" x="100" y="100" fill="deepPink" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @ccprog You were in such a hurry, surpassing that you did not notice that the author had changed the conditions. :-) Correct, please `transform-origin: 315px 184px; on  250px 250 px plus from me for speed (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_T not a hurry, but cross-posting ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with SMIL animations, then you'll need to use a little bit of Javascript.

```js
var svg = document.querySelector(".svg-gears");
svg.pauseAnimations();

svg.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  svg.unpauseAnimations();
});

svg.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  svg.pauseAnimations();
});
```

```html
<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; viewBox="0 0 500.1 489.1" class="svg-gears"> 
  <rect id="deepPink-rectangle" width="300" height="300" x="100" y="100" fill="deepPink" >
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform" 
      type="rotate"
      dur="6s"
      from="0 315 184"
      to="360 315 184"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
  </rect>
</svg>
```